# Microsoft Graph API - Create Contact doesn't work

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-contacts

I am attempting to use the Create Contacts endpoint for Microsoft Graph API (Doc is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to register  new contact for my user. I created body as described in API documentation but getting the error below:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "A value without a type name was found and no expected type is available. When the model is specified, each value in the payload must have a type which can be either specified in the payload, explicitly by the caller or implicitly inferred from the parent value.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "daf78520-50e6-444b-97a2-779762b3e6ed",
            "date": "2020-01-23T14:20:18"
        }
    }
}
```

Requests used:
1. POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{{tenant_id}}/contacts;
2. POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts;
Request body example:

```
{
  "givenName": "Yulia",
  "surname": "Lukianenko",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "address": "yulia@lukianenko.onmicrosoft.com",
      "name": "Yulia Lukianenko"
    }
  ],
  "businessPhones": [
    "+1 732 555 0102"
  ]
}
```

Did somebody meet such kind of issue? How you resolved it?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: That payload is fine, I just used it to POST to /me/contacts. Your first POST attempt won't work though, that URL isn't valid. You can't use a tenant ID. Have you tried making this request in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer)?

Comment: Jason Johnston, thank you for you reply! The behavior in Graph Explorer is the same. I suspect that this is problem with my license. What type of license do you use? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

POST request is incorrect here.
It should be :
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts

Also you need to make sure "Contacts.ReadWrite" permission is granted to the app registered in AAD.

P.S: I used the same JSON  in your example using graphExplorer and contact was created successfully.

Comment: Thank you, Abhijeet Jadhav, for reply! I had "Contacts.ReadWrite" permissions as delegated, added it for Application. The error is changed to : "{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a2e640bf-ff33-460f-ae03-7188cfe1ece3",
            "date": "2020-01-24T18:00:14"
        }
    }
}". It's the same in postman and in in Graph Explorer.

Comment: This appears to be permission issue. Were you able to successfully execute any 
 POST or GET request to any other endpoint in Postman? If yes, try this : In Postman, generate the access_token.  Once it is generated check the "Scope" parameter. It should have  - "https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.Read" , "https://graph.microsoft.com/Contacts.ReadWrite" entries.  Alternatively, You can also check the scope in the jwot decoder (https://jwt.ms/). Copy the access_token and paste it in token textbox.  If you dont see these scopes u need to check the permissions again.

Comment: Abhijeet Jadhav, I'm getting 200 for Get Contacts, Get Users, Get Groups, Create user, Create Group, Get group members in Postman only when I use tenant id in url like this https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{{tenant_id}}....When I use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me....It doesn't. For groups and users the error is : {
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "Resource '1ee41a2e-6032-487d-a6ef-e69075423c01' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.",

Comment: For contacts still the same "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource". Even after adding scope when generated token. Here are my roles from JWT: "roles": [
    "OrgContact.Read.All",
    "User.ReadWrite.All",
    "Application.ReadWrite.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Contacts.ReadWrite",
    "Organization.ReadWrite.All",
    "AppRoleAssignment.ReadWrite.All"
  ]. Audience is "aud": "https://graph.microsoft.com". Should be fine. Thank you in advance!

Comment: one question what type of license do you use? Thank you in advance!

Comment: I have "Office 365 E3 Developer" license